# Deprecation Synchronous XMLHttpRequest, pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i use this javascript code for a API request to get a JSON.

```
function loadJSON(url) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    xobj.open('GET', url, false);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            returnval = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
    return returnval;
}
```

The code is in a mouse-click event. The full URL is generated with data from the mouse click. The code is only work with sync. I have tested the code with async, but with this the code don't work.
    xobj.open('GET', file, true, null, null);

With sync, the console write:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

OK, hey! There a many Threads with this question, but i don't found a solution. I use pure JavaScript, no Ajax, no JQuery.

Comment: _"The code is only work with sync."_: You should add the "mouse-click" code as there's probably a way to get the code to work asynchronously.

Comment: You should *never* block the main thread as it stops user interactivity. You should be using asynchrony.

Comment: @Andy, there is a mouse-click-event with OpenLayers to get the coords, and the coords are writing in the request URL.

Comment: Consume the data in the `onreadystatechange` callback or return a promise that you resolve in `onreadystatechange`

Answer (score -2):

You almost have it written asynchronously. Pass in a callback function to get your `returnval`.

```js
function loadJSON(url, callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  xobj.open('GET', url);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
      returnval = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText);
      callback(returnval);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}

loadJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Still making synchronous request

Comment: @Will, OK, works, but i understand it. How we put i the result in a variable?

Comment: Ah, OK, i must put my complete code in place of the console.log().